# Q: Going from 2 lists of length n -> 1 list of length n, with sublists of length 2?

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray

To describe the problem with a small example input and desired output:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = expr

print(c)
>> [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

So I have come to a question about how to nicely perform this in a pythonic way.
What I have come up with is a list comprehension that does this nicely using zip, however it does feel like a bit of a cop-out using `zip` in the following manner:

```
[[x, y] for x, y in zip(a,b)]
```

Is there another way?

<s>Furthermore, since zip is not a solution for the general case with `m` lists of length `n`, that one wants to combine in the same way.</s>
*Edit:* As Dani Mesejo pointed out, Pythons zip built-in can take `m` iterables.

I'm mostly interested of nice plain python solutions.
I know that `numpy` can do this through nice nparray concatenations :)

Thanks!

Comment: That is the best way, and you can pass `m` lists to zip, you can even pass a list of list as argument to zip

Comment: To agree with @DaniMesejo - using the `zip` function is a Pythonic way to handle this.  It’s efficient, readable, and widely understood.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Ah! I have thought that zip produces 'two-ples', not a generic tuple. Thank you that really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Direct unpacking of `zip` with `*`:

```
[*zip(a,b)]
```

Will return a list of tuples, but for if you strictly want nested 2D list, then yours is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the chain function from itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

chain(zip(a,b))
```

Similar to the previous answer it will be a list of tuples. However, if your lists have more than 10.000.000 elements, I strongly recommend to use the chain function to achieve a better performance.

```
python -m timeit -n 10 "from itertools import chain;chain(zip(range(10000000),range(10000000)))"
10 loops, best of 5: 950 nsec per loop
```

```
python -m timeit -n 10 "[*zip(range(10000000),range(10000000))]"
10 loops, best of 5: 1.14 sec per loop
```